# Xamarin form - Instagram login: getting Invalid redirect_uri error, how to fix it?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, instagram, instagram-api

I have integrate Instagram login using Xamarin.Auth, I have referred:
[Instagram basic display api - Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started)
and in that first I was getting:

```cs
{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid scope field(s): basic"}
```

Then I have got this post: [C# Instagram - Invalid Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62647917/c-sharp-instagram-invalid-scope)

So I have updated everything and I have created New App in developers.facebook.com console under Instagram Basic Display product as mentioned in Instagram Getting Started document.

Then in code I have used that new App's App ID and also changed redirect url, also added Instagram Test users and they have accept invitations too, but now I am getting

```cs
{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid redirect_uri"}
```

---

**Auth code:**

```cs
var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
    clientId: Keys.InstagramClientId,  
    scope: "basic",  
    authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=" + Keys.InstagramClientId + "&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/callback&response_type=token"),
    redirectUrl: new Uri("https://localhost:3000/callback"))
{
    AllowCancel = true,
    ShowErrors = false,
    ClearCookiesBeforeLogin = true
};

AuthenticationState.Authenticator = authenticator;

authenticator.Error += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    activity.Finish();
};

authenticator.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        App.AccountType = "Instagram";
        App.SaveAccount(eventArgs.Account, view.IsFromReauthentication);
    }
};

var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
presenter.Login(authenticator);
```

---

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Finally I have make it work, sharing this as it might be help for someone looking for the solution!

---

```cs
var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(

// Id & App Secret of App you have created on FB developer console in Instagram Basic Display
clientId: Keys.InstagramAppId,
clientSecret: Keys.InstagramAppSecret,

// Basic scope is not supported anymore, this will fix Invalid scope error:
scope: "user_profile, user_media",

authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=" + Keys.InstagramAppId + "&redirect_uri=https://business.instagram.com/abc&response_type=token"),

accessTokenUrl: new Uri("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/"),

// Make sure that your redirect Url needs to register in developer console and it must be valid one
redirectUrl: new Uri("https://business.instagram.com/abc"))
{
    AllowCancel = true,
    ShowErrors = false,
    ClearCookiesBeforeLogin = true,
    IsLoadableRedirectUri = false
};

AuthenticationState.Authenticator = authenticator;

authenticator.Error += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Error - {eventArgs.Message}");
};

authenticator.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var userid = eventArgs.Account.Properties["user_id"];
        var access_token = eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"];
    }
};

var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
presenter.Login(authenticator);
```

---

#### To get user information:

`Request details using :`

```css
https://graph.instagram.com/me?fields=id,username&access_token
```

`Sample Response :`

```json
{
  "id": "17841405793187218",
  "username": "jayposiris"
}
```

#### Note: I have not got the way to get user's profile_picture, so if anyone know that solution please let me know.